# C/ why the List change

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//struct definition
typedef struct ListElement
    {
        char *value;
        struct ListElement *next;
    }ListElement, *List;

List push_back_list(List li, char *x);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char val[]= "12345678987456321069";      
    char dest[5];

    //here the list is empty
    List liste=new_list();
    strncpy(dest, val, 4);

    //push method
    liste=push_back_list(liste,dest);

    //modification of dest
    strncpy(dest, val+4, 4);

    //when i print list, the result were change without push method why??
    print_list(liste);  
    return 0;
}

//push method description
List push_back_list(List li, char *x)
{
    ListElement *element;

    element = malloc(sizeof(*element));
    element->value= x;
    element->next = NULL
    if(is_empty_list(li))
        return element;
    ListElement *temp;
    temp = li;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
        temp = temp->next;

    temp->next = element;
    return li;
}
```

Comment: `strncpy(dest, val, 4);` dest will not be null-terminated (it is uninialized, so`dest[4]`need **not** be zero.

Answer (score 3):

The list element doesn't store a copy of the string, it just stores a pointer to `dest`. When you change the contents of `dest`, that change is of course seen when you print it through the list element; it's the same buffer.

The fix is to create a copy in the list element, for instance by changing this:

```
element->value = x;
```

to:

```
element->value = strdup(x);
```

If you have `strdup()` (it's not standard, but common). Of course this opens you up to allocation failure. You can also make the list element contain a proper buffer, but that limits the size of the string you can support. Choices, choices. :)

Comment: Plus 1 (Because it wouldn't allow me a plus symbol, someone please flag it for being chatty, but let unwind read it once), specifically at *Choices, choices :)*.